# Using imagemagick to mask one image and output transparent png

Tags: python, imagemagick

I've gone nuts here. I'm simply trying to do the following with imagemagick and don't understand where im going one. I'm trying blend my colored image onto a transparent background using the illuminance of another image.

[image]

Here are the images:
Color: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9grpa6ustt92ve1/color.png?dl=0
Mask: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wfx5j5i4s03hh2i/mask.png?dl=0

The code below masks the colored image but doesn't create a transparent png as expected. It's filled black.

```
import subprocess

CONVERT_EXE = '.../convert.exe'

subprocess.run([CONVERT_EXE, solid, mask, '-alpha', 'off', '-compose', 'Multiply', '-composite', 'PNG32:' + output])
```

Comment: What the heck is `.../convert.exe` ?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/511

```
subprocess.run([CONVERT_EXE, solid, mask, '-alpha', 'off', '-compose', 'CopyOpacity', '-composite', '-background', 'black', '-alpha', 'Background', 'PNG32:' + output])
```